# Calculating the average lifetime values of customers between specific timeframes in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL I have an orders table that represents orders made by customers of a store, for example:

`SELECT * FROM orders`

| order_id | customer_id | value | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 200.00 | 2021-01-05 |
| 2 | 1 | 150.00 | 2021-01-07 |
| 3 | 1 | 99.50 | 2021-06-05 |
| 4 | 2 | 100.00 | 2021-03-03 |
| 5 | 2 | 21.50 | 2022-02-01 |
| 6 | 2 | 10.00 | 2022-03-04 |
| 7 | 3 | 5.00 | 2022-06-06 |

(Note that the real table won't be ordered by customer_id and created_at.)

First, I need to get all customers that made an order between a specified timeframe, e.g. 2021-01-01 to 2021-12-31. Using the data above, these are customers 1 and 2.

I then need to find the average value per customer over the following timeframes:

- 60-day
- 90-day
- 6-months
- 12-months

Customer 1's first purchase is 200.00 on 05-01-2021. We then need to add up the value of all purchases they made within 60-days, so 200.00 + 150.00 = 350.00.

For customer 2, the value of all purchases within 60 days of their first purchase is 100.00 (only their first purchase).

So, the average 60-day value per customer is (350.00 + 100.00) / 2 = 225.00.

We then need to do the same for 90-days, 6-months and 1-year from first purchase.

Final result should ideally look like this:

| timeframe | av_value_per_customer |
| --- | --- |
| 60-day | 225.00 |
| 90-day | 225.00 |
| 6-month | 274.75 |
| 1-year | 285.50 |

Comment: Unfortunately, your example is much too simple to understand what you want to get as a final result. What happens for example if customer 1 has made more orders in your time interval? Do you want to get the maximum 60-day value of this customer that you can find? Or the mean value? Or all 60-day intervals that you can find for a single customer? In any case, if you calculate the average over all customers, your mean value will be based on different 60-day intervals, is that intended?

Comment: If customer 1 made more purchases in the timeframe then they should be accounted for. The 60-day intervals will be different for each customer; for each customer, the timeframe will be their first purchase + 60-days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query must be structured in several steps. Let's implement it with `cte` :

First cte `customer_list` is to select the cutomers whose first order is in the target date range

Second cte `sum_list` is to calculate the sum of the order values for each customer on the different horizons

Last step is to calculate the average sum of order values for all the selected customers on the different horizons :

```
WITH customer_list AS (
  SELECT customer_id
       , (array_agg(created_at ORDER BY created_at))[1] AS first_created_at
    FROM orders
   GROUP BY customer_id
  HAVING (array_agg(created_at ORDER BY created_at))[1] <@ daterange('2021-01-01', '2021-12-31')
), sum_list AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (o.customer_id)
       o.customer_id
     , sum(o.value) FILTER (WHERE o.created_at <@ daterange(c.first_created_at, (c.first_created_at + interval '60 days') :: date)) OVER (PARTITION BY o.customer_id) AS avg_60d
     , sum(o.value) FILTER (WHERE o.created_at <@ daterange(c.first_created_at, (c.first_created_at + interval '90 days') :: date)) OVER (PARTITION BY o.customer_id) AS avg_90d
     , sum(o.value) FILTER (WHERE o.created_at <@ daterange(c.first_created_at, (c.first_created_at + interval '6 months') :: date)) OVER (PARTITION BY o.customer_id) AS avg_6m
     , sum(o.value) FILTER (WHERE o.created_at <@ daterange(c.first_created_at, (c.first_created_at + interval '12 months') :: date)) OVER (PARTITION BY o.customer_id) AS avg_12m
   FROM orders AS o
  INNER JOIN customer_list AS c
    ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
)
SELECT '60-day' AS timeframe, avg(avg_60d) :: decimal(12,2) AS av_value_per_customer
  FROM sum_list
UNION ALL
SELECT '90-day', avg(avg_90d) :: decimal(12,2)
  FROM sum_list
UNION ALL
SELECT '6-month', avg(avg_6m) :: decimal(12,2)
  FROM sum_list
UNION ALL
SELECT '1-year', avg(avg_12m) :: decimal(12,2)
  FROM sum_list
```

Result :

| timeframe | av_value_per_customer |
| --- | --- |
| 60-day | 225.00 |
| 90-day | 225.00 |
| 6-month | 274.75 |
| 1-year | 285.50 |

see the result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u5Q-wRxt)

Comment: Thanks @Edouard. Would this query take a while if the table was large, e.g. 400,000 rows? Do you think it could be better if I stored the 60-day, 90-day, 6-Mo and 1-Yr values for each customer in a table in my database, then query directly from there?

Comment: Difficult to tell you the performance of such a query. This query should not take a while if it relies on an index. I can suggest you to create a BTREE index on columns `customer_id` and `created_at` and then to run the query with ` ÈXPLAIN ANALYSE` so that to check if the query plan relies on this index.